# Create columns of relative values with a set starting base value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In python, I have a dataframe similar to this:

```py
print(transport)
```

```
year    cycles   cars     lorries       
1993    249      21000    1507
1994    249      21438    1539
1995    257      21817    1581
1996    253      22364    1630
1997    253      22729    1668
```

I would like to look at the change over time for each form of transport, relative to the earliest value i.e. for 1993. I would like to create a new dataframe based on `transport` where 1993 is the base year with the value set to 100.0 and all subsequent values be relative to that.

I'm really new to python and I can't figure out how to approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can divide all the values by the corresponding number from `1993` and multiply by 100.0 to get the results -

```py
df = df.set_index('year')
df / df.loc[1993] * 100.0
#           cycles        cars     lorries
# year                                    
# 1993  100.000000  100.000000  100.000000
# 1994  100.000000  102.085714  102.123424
# 1995  103.212851  103.890476  104.910418
# 1996  101.606426  106.495238  108.161911
# 1997  101.606426  108.233333  110.683477
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iterrows`:

```py
transport.set_index("year", inplace=True)

y1993 = transport[transport.index == 1993]

for index, row in transport.iterrows():
  for column in transport.columns:
    transport.loc[index, column] = ((row[column])/(y1993[column].values[0])) * 100
transport
```

##### Output

| year | cycles | cars | lorries |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1993 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
| 1994 | 100 | 102.086 | 102.123 |
| 1995 | 103.213 | 103.89 | 104.91 |
| 1996 | 101.606 | 106.495 | 108.162 |
| 1997 | 101.606 | 108.233 | 110.683 |